# Align JTextArea Bottom

Tags: java

I am doing a chat in java, with this code:

```
text += sendField.getText();
messageArea.setText(text);
```

And I got this:
[image]

But I want the text to be align in the bottom of the JTextArea is it possible?

**How can I turn it into this?**
[image]

Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the text to be align in the bottom of the JTextArea is it possible?

Text components don't support this. You would need to write a custom UI to have text paint from the bottom of the component instead of the top of the component (which is above my skill level).

However, you can take advantage of Swing layout managers to make it appear that the text is being displayed from the bottom:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class TextAreaBottom extends JPanel implements DocumentListener
{
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public TextAreaBottom(JTextArea textArea)
    {
        this.textArea = textArea;

        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        setBackground( textArea.getBackground() );
        setBorder( textArea.getBorder() );
        textArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);

        add(textArea, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        adjustHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        adjustHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e)  {}

    private void adjustHeight()
    {
        int rows = textArea.getLineCount();
        textArea.setRows(rows);
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
        textArea.setEditable( false );

        final JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
        JButton send = new JButton( "Send" );
        send.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if(textArea.getDocument().getLength() > 0)
                    textArea.append("\n");

                textArea.append( textField.getText() );

                textField.setText("");
                textField.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });

        JPanel panel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
        panel.add(textField);
        panel.add(send, BorderLayout.EAST);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextAreaBottom");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane( new TextAreaBottom(textArea) ) );
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Or for a better approach you can use a JTextPane. I modified the [Center Text Vertically in JTextPane](http://java-sl.com/tip_center_vertically.html) code to paint the text at the bottom. That was an easy one line change since the hard part was already done:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TextPaneCenter
{
    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JTextPane edit = new JTextPane();
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(edit));
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        edit.setSelectionColor( Color.GREEN );


        try
        {
            edit.setEditorKit(new MyEditorKit());
            SimpleAttributeSet attrs=new SimpleAttributeSet();
            StyleConstants.setAlignment(attrs,StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
            StyledDocument doc=(StyledDocument)edit.getDocument();
            doc.insertString(0,"111\n2222222\n33333333333333",attrs);
            doc.setParagraphAttributes(0,doc.getLength()-1,attrs,false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }

    static class MyEditorKit extends StyledEditorKit
    {
        public ViewFactory getViewFactory()
        {
            return new StyledViewFactory();
        }

        static class StyledViewFactory implements ViewFactory
        {
            public View create(Element elem)
            {
                String kind = elem.getName();

                if (kind != null)
                {
                    if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.ContentElementName))
                    {
                        return new LabelView(elem);
                    }
                    else if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.ParagraphElementName))
                    {
                        return new ParagraphView(elem);
                    }
                    else if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.SectionElementName))
                    {
                        return new CenteredBoxView(elem, View.Y_AXIS);
                    }
                    else if (kind.equals(StyleConstants.ComponentElementName))
                    {
                        return new ComponentView(elem);
                    }
                    else if (kind.equals(StyleConstants.IconElementName))
                    {
                        return new IconView(elem);
                    }
                }

            // default to text display
            return new LabelView(elem);
            }
        } // class StyledViewFactory
     } // class MyEditorKit

    static class CenteredBoxView extends BoxView
    {
        public CenteredBoxView(Element elem, int axis)
        {
            super(elem,axis);
        }

        protected void layoutMajorAxis(int targetSpan, int axis, int[] offsets, int[] spans)
        {
            super.layoutMajorAxis(targetSpan,axis,offsets,spans);

            int textBlockHeight = 0;
            int offset = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < spans.length; i++)
            {
                textBlockHeight += spans[ i ];
            }

            // display text vertically at the bottom
            offset = (targetSpan - textBlockHeight);

            // display text vertically centered
            //offset = (targetSpan - textBlockHeight) / 2;

            for (int i = 0; i < offsets.length; i++)
            {
                offsets[ i ] += offset;
            }
        }
    }
}
```